# How do I make my cards not so wide and have 3 columns

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

So I have this page with a few cards (15 or so) and the goal is that I want to show them all in a grid like fashion, 3 columns and 5 rows.
For some reason it's only showing 2 columns though and I'm not sure why. I tried setting the width of the cards using `w-25` but that makes it to where it starts looking really strange when I start shrinking the webpage.

This is where I set `w-25` and that makes it to where the cards dont stack when the page shrinks, they just get squished together

```
<div class="card card-with-border ml-2 mr-2 mt-5 w-25">
```

And here is the code for the cards, I removed the `w-25` from the code below.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center mb-4">

    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <div class="card card-with-border ml-2 mr-2 mt-5 ">
            <div class="card-body mb-0">
                @foreach (var item in user.Tags)
                {
                    <span class="badge badge-primary mt-3 ml-0">@item</span>
                }
            </div>

            <div class="card-body socialprofile filter-cards-view pt-2">


                <div class="media">

                    <div class="avatar ratio"><img class="b-r-8 height-50 mr-3 img-80" src=@user.Image alt="#"></div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h6 class="font-danger f-w-600">Hello, World!</h6>

                        <h5><i class="icofont icofont-social-snapchat"></i></h5>
                        <span class="card-text"><h5><i class="icofont icofont-social-instagram"></i></h5><p></p></span>
                        <p class="card-text mt-2">Testing the text lets see what it looks like.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="social-btngroup d-flex">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary w-100">Like</button>
                </div>
                <div class="likes-profile text-center">
                    <h5> <span> <i class="fa fa-heart font-danger"></i> 884</span></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your cards in div's with `col-4`, so 3 columns per row. Then just add the required padding. `<div class="col-4 px-2">`

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center mb-4">     
    @foreach (var user in Model)
            {     
        <div class="col-4 px-2">
              <div class="card card-with-border mt-5 ">
                        <div class="card-body mb-0">
                            @foreach (var item in user.Tags)
                            {
                                <span class="badge badge-primary mt-3 ml-0">@item</span>
                            }
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="card-body socialprofile filter-cards-view pt-2">
            
            
                            <div class="media">
            
                                <div class="avatar ratio"><img class="b-r-8 height-50 mr-3 img-80" src=@user.Image alt="#"></div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h6 class="font-danger f-w-600">Hello, World!</h6>
            
                                    <h5><i class="icofont icofont-social-snapchat"></i></h5>
                                    <span class="card-text"><h5><i class="icofont icofont-social-instagram"></i></h5><p></p></span>
                                    <p class="card-text mt-2">Testing the text lets see what it looks like.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="social-btngroup d-flex">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary w-100">Like</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="likes-profile text-center">
                                <h5> <span> <i class="fa fa-heart font-danger"></i> 884</span></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
        
        }
    </div>
```